# WebServer listen on SSL and all addresses

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

I'm implementing a signalR self-hosted service using asp.net OWIN.

My server initialization looks something like this-

```
string url = "https://*:443";  
WebApplication.Start<MyConfigurations>(url);
```

and on the client side-

```
var hubUrl = 'https://1.mydomain.com:443';
connection = $.hubConnection(hubUrl);
```

On the client side, I'm getting a 404 error while negotiating connection to signalR.
If I change the url on the server side to `string url = "https://mydomain.com:443";`, it works fine.

how do I configure the `WebApplication` to listen to all requests arriving to the server on port 443 (or any other port, using SSL), regardless of the URL that the client used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure nothing else is registered to listen on 443? 'Cause * is a "weak" wildcard and if something else is listening on that port using a "stronger" URL registration than that it would explain why it does not work.

So, first, try `https://+:443` and see if that works or even specify a base path like `https://+:443/SignalRTest`. That's the strongest possible form of wildcard. If you're still having issues, I'd check to make sure there are no other registrations for 443 with something like:

```
netsh http show urlacl
```